# Relay module doing crazy things

Tags: arduino, relay

I have a problem. I am trying to read 3 sensors and if one of them is under a certain value, a pump should be powered. Everything works, until I connect the pump to the relay. When doing so, the Arduino stops sampling and powers all 3 pumps one after one.

I have tried to power the relay module with a second power supply, I have tried it with and without a common ground, nothing worked. I don't think it is a program error as it works if the power supply of the pumps is not active.

This is my relay module:

https://funduinoshop.com/bauelemente/taster-und-schalter/relais/relaiskarte.-high-low-level-trigger-8-kanal-5v

This is the code:

```
int t1 = 600; // Zeit zwischen Proben in ms

int Sensor1 = A0;
int Sensor2 = A1;
int Sensor3 = A2;

int messwert1 = 0;
int prozent1 = 0;

int messwert2 = 0;
int prozent2 = 0;

int messwert3 = 0;
int prozent3 = 0;

int messwert1max = 635;
int messwert1min = 260;

int messwert2max = 637;
int messwert2min = 264;

int messwert3max = 637;
int messwert3min = 266;

int Pumpe1 = 2;
int Pumpe2 = 3;
int Pumpe3 = 4;

int tp1 = 1000;
int tp2 = 1000;
int tp3 = 1000;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(Pumpe1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pumpe2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pumpe3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  messwert1 = analogRead(Sensor1);
  messwert2 = analogRead(Sensor2);
  messwert3 = analogRead(Sensor3);

  prozent1 = map(messwert1, messwert1min, messwert1max, 100, 0);
  prozent2 = map(messwert2, messwert2min, messwert2max, 100, 0);
  prozent3 = map(messwert3, messwert3min, messwert3max, 100, 0);

  if (prozent1 <= 70)
  {
    digitalWrite(Pumpe1, HIGH);
    delay(tp1);
    digitalWrite(Pumpe1, LOW);
  }

  if (prozent2 <= 70)
  {
    digitalWrite(Pumpe2, HIGH);
    delay(tp2);
    digitalWrite(Pumpe2, LOW);
  }

  if (prozent3 <= 70)
  {
    digitalWrite(Pumpe3, HIGH);
    delay(tp3);
    digitalWrite(Pumpe3, LOW);
  }

  Serial.print(prozent1);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(prozent2);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(prozent3);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(0);

  delay(t1);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The relay module has optoisolators specifically to avoid this kind of issue.

You have bypassed them with your connection scheme- the Arduino should have a completely independent power supply with no direct connection (such as a common ground) between the two power supplies.

I don't see enough information on the relay module web page you have linked to be 100% sure how to do that- for example, the jumper function is not obvious to me.

This kind of relay is not really great for switching inductive motor loads like pump motors. Poor coil-contact isolation, poor contact open gap, and low contact capacity. So don't expect too much considering the entire 8-relay module costs a fraction of what a single good heavy motor load rated relay (the component, not a module) such as Omron G7L. It may work well enough depending on your pump construction, but there is not even an inductive load rating (let alone motor rating) for 230VAC mains voltage on the SRD relays.

Comment: Thank you, I also tried it by powering the relay module via the arduino and have the second power supply just for the pumps. That does not solve the problem. even though the 2 circuits should be separated completely. If you have a other suggestion on how to power it , please show me. As for the relay module, for my application it should be enough, as i just switch 5V with a few mA. I feel like there is a problem with my relay module. I will try it later with 3 separate relays.